# Comment ça se prononce "au début" ?

Tags: prononciation

La traduction de Google prononce "au début" [en une manière un peu bizarre](https://translate.google.com/#fr/en/au%20d%C3%A9but), comme "o debooss". Est-ce que ça se prononce comme ça ?

Comment: Très mauvaise prononciation. Google traduction n'est pas fiable, ni pour la traduction, ni pour la prononciation. Écouter [*au début* sur Shtooka](http://shtooka.net/view_sound.php?id=7698).  Shtooka propose des enregistrements humains, pas des robots ! /odeby/

Comment: @Laure merci beaucoup ! Shtooka a l'air excellent !

Comment: [Shtooka](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shtooka) c'est génial. [**Fiable**](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/fiable). Et oui, google traduction est plutôt  f**ai**ble. Pour les traductions préférer Reverso ou Linguee.

Comment: [Forvo](http://fr.forvo.com/word/au_d%C3%A9but/#fr) est aussi une excellente ressource pour apprendre les prononciations.

Comment: @Gilles  Je suis d'accord que cette question devait être fermée mais le motif donné (proposé par l'interface je suppose) n'est pas vraiment approprié.